# Convergence of a sequence versus continuity of a function

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove the following result about metric spaces (for self study).

> Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence in $(X,d)$, $Z := \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\} \cup \{0\}$, and $f: Z \to X$ the map sending $\frac{1}{n} \mapsto p_n$ and $0 \mapsto p$. Then $p_n \to p$ if and only if $f$ is continuous.

I believe this is a general metric space $X$, so I can't refer to $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric, which is the most "natural" thing for me to think of. Here is my attempt at both directions.

$(\implies)$

> Suppose $p_n \to p$. We need to show that for all $z \in Z$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $z' \in Z$ $d_Z (z,z') < \delta$ implies $d_X (f(z), f(z')) < \epsilon$.

The biggest problem I see is that there are two completely different metrics at play, and I'm not sure how a choice for $\delta$ to bound the metric on $Z$ allows me to say anything about the metric on $X$. The lecture notes I'm working through haven't yet defined continuity in terms of preimages of open sets, so I don't think I can invoke that definition just yet.

$(\Leftarrow)$

> Suppose $f$ is continuous. We need to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N > 0$ such that for every $n \geq N$, $d_X(p_n, p) < \epsilon$. I don't yet have a notion of continuity in sequences, so I need to somehow prove this directly. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. As $f$ is continuous, it is continuous at $0$. So I can find $\delta> 0$ so that for every $z' \in Z$ satisfying $d_Z (z', 0) < \delta$, we have $d_X (f(z'), 0) < \epsilon$.

The problem is, I don't know how this relates to a choice of $N$, and I can't figure out how to treat the case where $z' = 0$ itself, though that case seems immediate, as $d_X (0,0) = 0 < \epsilon$, though do I need to treat that case entirely separately?

I would appreciate any help on how to prove these facts.

Comment: Are you assuming the standard metric on $\mathbb{Z}$? Also, small typo on the reverse implication: $d_X(f(z'),0)$ should be $d_X(f(z'),f(0))$ and $d_X(0,0)$ should be $d_X(f(0),f(0))$

Comment: @nicoyanovsky Thanks for noticing the typo. And I believe the notes I'm working through don't assume a metric on $X$ or on $Z$, which is especially confusing to me.

Comment: The metric on $X$ doesn't actually matter. As an example, for the reverse implication, if we assume the standard metric on $\mathbb{Z}$, then any $z' \in Z$ is of the form $\frac{1}{m}, m \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that taking $N=m$ suffices, since $n > N \implies d_Z(\frac{1}{n}, 0) = \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} < \delta$

Comment: @nicoyanovsky This seems to me to prevent a few different cases because $z' = 0$ is possible and I want to prove continuity at a general $z \in Z$. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that $0 \in Z$, but it doesn't actually matter, since for any $\delta > 0$ there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{m} < \delta$. Taking $N=m$ suffices, as I wrote in my last comment, since for all $n > m$, $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{m} < \delta \implies d_X(f(\frac{1}{n}),f(0)) = d_X(p_n, p) < \epsilon$

Comment: @nicoyanovsky That makes more sense, but why can we assume the standard metric on $Z$? I'm still confused by this.

Comment: Oh, we can't. I just did because I see no other way to prove this. It is common to work with the standard metric when the space is specified and not an abstract one, as in this case. The claim is also not true for any metric: if $Z$ is endowed with the discrete metric, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ the only point at which $d_Z(z',0) < \delta$ is $z'=0$, so whatever $N$ you choose there's no $n>N$ such that $d_Z(\frac{1}{n},0) < \delta$, so $p_n$ and $p$ will always be at least $\epsilon$ away